# How fix this error :currently no loaders are configured to process this file?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, binary, webpack-file-loader, hdr

I create larval 8 and react mix projects. I add three js for that project. It has hdr-type assets in the assets folder. I got the below error. Can you help me to fix this error?

[image: error image]

[image: webpack.config.js]

Comment: Please share your webpack configuration file.

Comment: It is an empty file. I know that put module into that. But I do not what I should put into the config file.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Now I put my webpack.config.js code photo

Comment: Try `file-loader` instead of `raw-loader`. Raw loader tries to read the file as a string

Comment: still got this error @AmilaSenadheera